# Why does Python let you instantiate local variables as global from inside a function?

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

Why does the below work in Python, without declaring **a** in the global scope first?

```
def setA():
   global a 
   a = 5

def printA():
    print a

setA()
printA()
```

It seems to me that this is the correct way to do it:

```
a = None

def setA():
   global a 
   a = 5

def printA():
    print a

setA()
printA()
```

Comment: What's the alternative? Should `global` silently fail if `a` does not exist in the global scope and let it be local instead? Should it raise an exception?

Comment: I was under the impression that the global keyword meant "the following refers to the variable in the global scope".

I would think when you do "print a" there should be an error that the variable is unknown.

Comment: @Stewart: It doesn't mean that, it means "any uses of the following name are now considered to be operating in global scope".  It doesn't matter whether the name already exists there or not.  If you assign to it and it wasn't there, it creates it, just like it would if you actually assigned to it at the module top-level.

Comment: @BrenBarn Ok, that makes sense.  Would it still be better style to do it like in my second chunk of code instead of the first way?

Comment: @Stewart: It probably makes sense to do something along those lines, although `None` is maybe not the best choice.  Usually you'd only use global variables for some sort of global config option, so you'd set an initial, useful default value and then possibly change it later.  But yeah, to make the code more readable it's good to have the global defined early.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically for the same reason that `a = 5` works to create a new local variable: when you assign to a variable, Python doesn't care whether it exists already or not.  The `global` statement simply means "any uses of the following name in this scope are now considered to be operating in global scope".

You can do `a = 5` at the module top level whether `a` exists already or not.  So you can do `global a; a = 5` inside a function.  `global` makes the assignment inside the function work just like the one at the global level, including the fact that it doesn't matter whether the name already exists or not.

Comment: +1. Of course try this with `nonlocal` in Python 3… (The difference here is that `global a; a = 5` cannot possibly be ambiguous—it has an obvious meaning, and that's the meaning that the compiler uses.)

Comment: Note that we can modify mutable global objects without using any `global` statement.